# With MDX how to sort by month

Tags: mdx

How do I sort by month. Now the sorting is alfabetical. And that is not correct. I want january before april - not the other way run :)

Im working in report builder 3.0 and have tried this (=format(Fields!Måned.Value,"MM") as a calculated member called monthsort, but it dosent Work. (Måned = month in Danish).

I have the following MDX-code:

```
WITH 
  SET [prodSet] AS 
    [Borger].[Anonym Borgernøgle DPR].[Anonym Borgernøgle DPR].ALLMEMBERS
  SET [prodDtSet] AS 
    NonEmpty
    (
        [prodSet]
      * 
        {
            ( [SundhedOgOmsorg - Ydelse].[Ydelse].[Ydelse].ALLMEMBERS *
              [Kalender].[År].[År].ALLMEMBERS * 
              [Kalender].[Måned].[Måned].ALLMEMBERS )
        }
     ,[Measures].[Antal unikke brugere - Visiteret Tid]
    ) 
  SET [prodDtSetFiltered] AS 
    Filter
    (
      [prodDtSet]
     ,
        (NOT 
            [prodDtSet].Item(
            [prodDtSet].CurrentOrdinal - 1).Item(0)
          IS 
            [prodDtSet].Item(
            [prodDtSet].CurrentOrdinal - 2).Item(0))
      OR 
        [prodDtSet].CurrentOrdinal = 1
    ) 
SELECT 
  { [Measures].[Antal unikke brugere - Visiteret Tid] } ON 0
 ,[prodDtSetFiltered] ON 1
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {
      [SundhedOgOmsorg - Ydelse].[Ydelse].&[12.1 Hjemmetrænerforløb]
     ,[SundhedOgOmsorg - Ydelse].[Ydelse].&[12.2 Komb. Hjemmetræner & Terapeutforløb]
     ,[SundhedOgOmsorg - Ydelse].[Ydelse].&[12.3 Komplekse Rehabiliteringsforløb]
     ,[SundhedOgOmsorg - Ydelse].[Ydelse].&[12.7. hverdagsrehab. revis.gr. m. tp.]
    } ON COLUMNS
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      {[SundhedOgOmsorg - Modul].[Modul].&[Hjemmehjælp]} ON COLUMNS
    FROM [FrbLis]
  )
)
WHERE 
  [SundhedOgOmsorg - Modul].[Modul].&[Hjemmehjælp]
```

Comment: you have this on rows `{ [Measures].[Antal unikke brugere - Visiteret Tid] } ` and this on columns `{ [Measures].[Antal unikke brugere - Visiteret Tid] }` ....where is month?

Comment: You've got two good answers in MDX. But you can try to do the sorting at report level too. SSRS/Excel is a better tool when it comes to data presentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and pull the

```
MEMBER [Measures].[MånedSortKey] AS [Kalender].[Måned].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES('KEY')
```

You can also use **MEMBER_KEY** instead of **PROPERTIES('KEY')**

And Sort by it in the report.
(I'm assuming your Key is a Date or a Int which should be more sortable than a string)

```
(...)
MEMBER [Measures].[MånedSortKey] AS [Kalender].[Måned].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES('KEY')
SELECT 
    { 
        [Measures].[Antal unikke brugere - Visiteret Tid],
        [Measures].[MånedSortKey] 
    } ON 0,
    [prodDtSetFiltered] ON 1
FROM (
(...)
```

Comment: good answer - upped - although it is possible to sort in the `mdx` rather than in the client

Comment: @whytheq Yes indead, your answer already covers that possibility. I find this way a bit more friendly and will give you the ability to sort each tablix with it's own DESC/ASC/composite ordering.

Comment: (I'm just an mdx junkie - so if I can do something in there, then I will)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use the following function in your script:

`Order` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145587.aspx

The `<numeric expression>` to use as an argument will be the Month member's `.membervalue` property.

Taking `mxix` measure (I've used membervalue rather than key - although both should work) you should be able to enforce an order inside the `mdx`:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[MånedSortKey] AS 
    [Kalender].[Måned].CURRENTMEMBER.membervalue
  SET [prodSet] AS 
    [Borger].[Anonym Borgernøgle DPR].[Anonym Borgernøgle DPR].ALLMEMBERS
  SET [prodDtSet] AS 
    NonEmpty
    (
        [prodSet]
      * 
        {
            ( [SundhedOgOmsorg - Ydelse].[Ydelse].[Ydelse].ALLMEMBERS *
              [Kalender].[År].[År].ALLMEMBERS * 
              [Kalender].[Måned].[Måned].ALLMEMBERS )
        }
     ,[Measures].[Antal unikke brugere - Visiteret Tid]
    ) 
  SET [prodDtSetFiltered] AS 
    Filter
    (
      [prodDtSet]
     ,
        (NOT 
            [prodDtSet].Item(
            [prodDtSet].CurrentOrdinal - 1).Item(0)
          IS 
            [prodDtSet].Item(
            [prodDtSet].CurrentOrdinal - 2).Item(0))
      OR 
        [prodDtSet].CurrentOrdinal = 1
    ) 
SELECT 
  { [Measures].[Antal unikke brugere - Visiteret Tid] } ON 0
 ,ORDER(
   [prodDtSetFiltered],
   [Measures].[MånedSortKey],
   BDESC
  ) ON 1
FROM 
...
...
```